# auto_refresh of external tables which load from S3

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The [docs for](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-external-table) `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE` state, for the `AUTO_REFRESH` property,

> Setting this parameter to TRUE is not supported for external tables that reference data files stored on an S3-compatible external stage. You must manually refresh the metadata by executing an ALTER EXTERNAL TABLE … REFRESH command.

I am confused, does this apply when the external stage references S3 itself, or only when it is some other "S3-compatible" location?

(Background: I have been using the DBT Macro `dbt-external-tables` to create external tables, and have noticed that these tables do not actually get the `AUTO_REFRESH` property set on them (according to the response from `SELECT GET_DDL([mytable])`) even when I have `auto_refresh: true` on the table. This has made me suspicious that it is being stripped.)

Comment: It only applies to S3-compatible storage, not to S3 storage itself. If you are using actual S3 then as well as setting this parameter to TRUE you would need to set up event notification: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-external-s3